# QPushButton shortcut does not work properly

Tags: python, pyqt5

In this simple pyqt5 app, I have a `QPushButton` and I define a shortcut for it. I want to change its text every time it is triggered. Problem is that the shortcut works only for the first time. How can I fix it?

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton, QMainWindow, QApplication
import sys

class window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(window, self).__init__()
        self.btn = QPushButton('&Connect', self)
        self.btn.setShortcut('Ctrl+C')
        self.btn.pressed.connect(self.btn_func)

    def btn_func(self):
        if self.btn.text() == '&Connect':
            self.btn.setText('Dis&connect')
        else:
            self.btn.setText('&Connect')


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the [`text`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#text-prop) property documentation [emphasis mine]:

> If the text contains an ampersand character ('&'), a shortcut is automatically created for it. [...] **Any previous shortcut will be overwritten or cleared if no shortcut is defined by the text**

I know that the above might seem confusing, as it seems that the shortcut is overwritten or cleared *only if* no shortcut is defined by the text, consider it like this:

> Any previous shortcut will be overwritten**, or it is cleared** if no shortcut is defined by the text

The solution is to always reset the shortcut *after* setting the new text:

```
    def btn_func(self):
        if self.btn.text() == '&Connect':
            self.btn.setText('Dis&connect')
        else:
            self.btn.setText('&Connect')
        self.btn.setShortcut('Ctrl+C')
```

Note that using the button's text for comparison is considered bad practice, for three reasons:

1. the text of a button could (should) be localized;
2. you could easily forget to correctly update all the `&` texts, making the function behave in the wrong way;
3. some QStyles override existing mnemonics and change them by themselves, which also causes the `text` to change without any warning;

The most preferred way to achieve what you want would be to use an internal flag for the current state, and also a QAction with its own shortcut.

```
class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.btn = QPushButton('&Connect', self)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.btn_func)

        self.connectAction = QAction('Toggle connection', self)
        self.connectAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+c')
        self.connectAction.triggered.connect(self.btn.animateClick)
        self.addAction(self.connectAction)

        self.connected = False

    def btn_func(self):
        self.connected = not self.connected
        if self.connected:
            self.btn.setText('Dis&connect')
        else:
            self.btn.setText('&Connect')
```

Also note that:

1. you should not use the `pressed()` signal, as it's standard convention to consider a button clicked when the user presses **and** releases the mouse button while inside the button area (so that the pressed action could be "undone" by moving the mouse away if the mouse button was pressed by mistake on the button); use the `clicked()` signal instead;
2. I changed the class name using a capitalized `Window`, as classes should always use capitalized names and lower cased names should only be used for functions and variables;
3. I used the `animateClick` slot to show that the button was clicked (as a visual feedback is always preferable), but you can directly connect to the function: `self.connectAction.triggered.connect(self.btn_func)`;